# Add edit/delete icon to row of data populated by JSOn (AjaxCall)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML table which is being populated by a JSON (ajax call).  In the Edit and Delete columns of the table I need to have an icon to edit or delete the data on each row.

I don't know how to add the icon when the table is populated by the JSON.

Following is my code:

//JSON which is populating the table.  Register.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var allRegister = AjaxCall(apiUrl, mthdGetReleasesFullList, null,   
    {

    });

    var data=allRegister.responseText;  
    alert("testing"+ data);
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data);
        //var table = $('#contact-data').DataTable({
            var table = $('#register-data').DataTable({
                    "data": jsonResponse.data,
                    "columns": [
                    { "data": "ReleaseID" },
                    { "data": "ReleaseName" },
                    { "data": "DivisionID" },
                     { "data": "StatusID" },   
                    ],

                    "order": [[1, 'dsc']]      
                });

});
```

Html code for table:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="entity/Register/css/Register.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Page specific JS -->
<script src="entity/Register/js/Register.js"></script>

<div class="container-full">

    <div class="heading-1">
        <input type="button" id="btn-AddUser" value="Add Release" style="font-size:14px;color:teal;text-align: left"> 
            <h1>


            </h1>

        <div class="modular-box-text inset">

          <div class="retgister-table-holder">
            <h2>Pre-Release Access Register:</h2>
            <br>
                <div class="register-table" >   

                <table id="register-data"class="display tablesorter" role="grid" aria-describedby="example_info"  style="width: 100%;" cellspacing="0"> 

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ReleaseID</th>
                            <th>ReleaseName</th>
                            <th>DivisionID</th> 
                            <th>StatusIDth>   
                            <th>Edit<th>    
                            <th>Delete </th>             
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                </table>    
                </div>  

            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to add the icons to the table, with the style display prop set to `none`, and, when the request is complete, set the whole `edit` and `delete` icons display to `block` using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with the `render` option of the `columns` objects - [documentation here](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers). When you specify the targeted ID of your desired action (i presume it is `ReleaseID`) you just create more columns with that ID as `data` object and adjust the column renderer by giving it a custom `render` method. Since you specified `ReleaseID` as `data`, you can re-use that value in the `render` method as first argument.

In the example below you can see how to achieve this - You can very easily replace `Edit` and `Delete` text with `<img />` tags referencing the icons you want to have for each action.

```js
// Faking a request
var response = [
    { "ReleaseID": "1", 
      "ReleaseName": "Release A",
      "DivisionID": "10",
      "StatusID": "1"
    }, {
      "ReleaseID": "2", 
      "ReleaseName": "Release B",
      "DivisionID": "9",
      "StatusID": "2"
    }, {
      "ReleaseID": "3", 
      "ReleaseName": "Release C",
      "DivisionID": "9",
      "StatusID": "1"
    }, {
      "ReleaseID": "4", 
      "ReleaseName": "Release D",
      "DivisionID": "10",
      "StatusID": "2"
    }, {
      "ReleaseID": "5", 
      "ReleaseName": "Release E",
      "DivisionID": "11",
      "StatusID": "1"
    }];

$(document).on('ready', function() {
  $('#register-data').dataTable({
    "data": response,
    "columns": [
      { "data": "ReleaseID" },
      { "data": "ReleaseName" },
      { "data": "DivisionID" },
      { "data": "StatusID" },
      { 
        "data": "ReleaseID",
        "render": (data, type, row, meta) => `<a href="/releases/edit/${data}">Edit</a>`
      }, {
        "data": "ReleaseID",
        "render": (data, type, row, meta) => `<a href="/releases/delete/${data}">Delete</a>`
      }
    ],
    "order": [[1, 'dsc']] 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="register-data"class="display tablesorter" role="grid" aria-describedby="example_info"  style="width: 100%;" cellspacing="0"> 
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ReleaseID</th>
            <th>ReleaseName</th>
            <th>DivisionID</th>
            <th>StatusID</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.
I used the following to get Edit and Delete buttons to appear on all rows of table

```
    var table = $('#register-data').DataTable({

               "data": jsonResponse.data,
                "columns": [
                { "data": "ReleaseID" },
                { "data": "ReleaseName" },
                { "data": "DivisionID" },
                { "data": "StatusID" },
                {"data":null,      "defaultContent": "<button class='btn-Edit'>Edit</button>"},                
                 {"data":null,      "defaultContent": "<button class='btn-Delete'>Click!</button>"},            
                ],                             
                "order": [[1, 'dsc']]                       
            });
```